# Show a different circle for each marker in Google Maps?

Tags: php, android, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have a table that contains id, name, radius, latitude, & longitude columns. I want to mark some places in Google Maps with different circles on it. Is it possible? I try to use this method:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('peta'), options);
    var locations = [
        <?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($a_peta, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        ['<?php echo $rs['nama'] ?>', <?php echo $rs['latitude'] ?>, <?php echo $rs['longitude'] ?>],
        <?php } ?>
    ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
     /* kode untuk menampilkan banyak marker */
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'pics/ico.jpg'
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: '<?php echo $rs['radius'] ?>',    
            fillColor: '#AA0000'
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to show different circle for each marker in google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Make *radius* a number, not a string:

```
radius: <?php echo $rs['radius'] ?>,
```

Remember that radius is in meters, and it must be high enough value to be visible on the map.
P.S. In the case you need to draw circles of raduis calculated in screen pixels regardless of map zoom, you must use another technique.

Comment: your last sentence is exactly what I'm trying to know here. I want to draw circles of radius with different size for each marker.

what kind of technic?